How to call a view function of a smart contract from Go?
couldn't find solution to above problem online so posting it here:
for golang we need to use go-ethereum package for doing smart contract related operations. it is similar to ethers.js we use in javascript for smart contract operations.
import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc"
)

// Connect to the Ethereum client
    client, err := rpc.Dial("<rpc_node_url>")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to create client due to error:  %s", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // Address of the smart contract
    contractAddress := "<contract_address_here>"

    // abi of the function to be executed
    contractABI := []byte(`<function_abi_here>`)

    // parsing ABI of the function to be executed
    parsedABI := abi.ABI{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(contractABI, &parsedABI)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error while unmarshaling abi: %s", err)
    }

    inputData, err := parsedABI.Pack("<function_name_here>", <args_comma_seperated_here>)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to pack input data due to error: %s", err)
    }

    var invokeResponse string

    // Call a view function of the smart contract
    err = client.Call(&invokeResponse, "eth_call", map[string]interface{}{
        "to":   contractAddress,
        "data": hex.EncodeToString(inputData),
    }, "latest")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to call contract due to error: %s", err)
    }

    // Decode the hex response into bytes
    data, err := hexutil.Decode(invokeResponse)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to decode invoke hex response due to error: %s", err)
    }
    var resp responseStruct
    err = parsedABI.UnpackIntoInterface(&resp, "<function_name_here>", data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to unpack invoke response due to error: %s", err)
    }

couldn't find solution to above problem online was thinking of directly using some package for the solution

This is just a very quick answer but should give you what you need. Here is a function to make the call "balanceOf" to an erc20 contract:
func ERC20GetBalanceOf(ctx context.Context, client *ethclient.Client, erc20Abi *abi.ABI, tokenAddr *common.Address,
    queryAddr *common.Address) (*big.Int, error) {
    balanceData, err := erc20Abi.Pack("balanceOf", queryAddr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error packing balanceOf data %w", err)
    }
    balanceMsg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        To:   tokenAddr,
        Data: balanceData,
    }
    balanceResult, err := client.CallContract(ctx, balanceMsg, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error calling balanceOf function: %w", err)
    }
    balance, err := erc20Abi.Unpack("balanceOf", balanceResult)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error unpacking balanceOf result: %w", err)
    }
    return balance[0].(*big.Int), nil
}

Of course you can go and use lower levels calls like the client.Call if you follow correctly how what's being done under the hood in client.CallContract(ctx, balanceMsg, nil).
But I believe what I gave you is the most common way to do so without a generated abi binding function like it is described in goethereumbook
